# Regular Expression (how to return a whole string)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to add a space in the begin of each string in the text, so I need to return a whole string with RegExp

I have tried `regme = /^$/g;` but it doesn't work, I know I am wrong, so how it must be right?
I found the answer var = /\n/g; but it doesn't work with line number 0, it's mean that I choose all new lines after first string, except first string, but I need first string too, pls ppl help?

Comment: `^$` matches an empty string.

Comment: Where's your string coming from?

Comment: @meouw: I assume he wants to add a space before every word

Comment: do you want to add an space at the begining of each word or line? can you post an example of the String?

Comment: What is a `string in the text` ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to replace `\n` with `\n` and add single space to begining of the string.

This could be achieved using `replace()`:

```
var str = "x\ny\nz";
str.replace(/(\n|^)/, "$1 ");
```

Comment: thanx, it's the same what I need!

Answer (score 0):

```
/.*/g
```

This will return the whole string except new lines

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used regex in Javascript, but something like this should work:

search: `/^(.+)$/`

replace: `/ $1/`

Comment: Thats a space before the dollar sign in the replace string.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right you want this:

```
text = text.replace(/(.+)/ig, " $1");
```